# Type qualifier appear in multiple item declaration (exhibiting strange behavior with pointer)

Tags: c++

When I try to do this:

```
   int Var_1 =3, const Var_2 =34;
```

It throws an error and I understand it that (any) **type qualifier** `const` can't appear after first comma in a multiple item declaration (as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/888bfst6.aspx)) but when the qualifier is raised with a pointer, it changes its behaviour"

```
   int Var_1 =3, *const Var_2 = &Var_1; //works fine
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Short answer: because the standard says so. Long answer: seriously, because the standard says so

Comment: This is simply due to the grammar of C++ doesn't allow this.

Comment: Just don't do the multiple declaration with `,`, many do not consider it good coding style anyway.

Comment: In the latter, the `const` qualifies the `*`, not the `int`.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: *"Doctor, doctor it hurts when I do this!"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the strange way that declarations work in C++, which was inherited from C.

The general structure of declarations like those shown in the question is as follows: you have a sequence of *specifiers*, followed by one or more comma-separated *declarators*, where each declarator may have an optional *initializer*.

The keywords `const` and `int` are specifiers, so they go at the beginning. Each of the specifiers modifies all of the declarators. For example:

```
const int *x, y[10];
```

In this declaration there are two specifiers, namely `const` and `int`, and two declarators, namely `*x` and `y[10]`. Each of the two specifiers modifies both of the declarators.

The type information described by the specifiers can only occur at the beginning, as all specifiers must precede all declarators. That is a rule of the language.

However, some type information is carried by the declarators. Obviously `x` and `y` have different types in the above declaration even though they are being modified by the same specifiers; `x` is a pointer type while `y` is an array type. A declarator can be thought of as consisting of the name of the entity being declared, together with some operators. The `*` operator creates a pointer, while the `[]` operator creates an array. Such operators may be combined and nested, and their precedence may be changed with parentheses.

We may interpret `*const Var_2` as a declarator by considering `*const` as an operator that produces a `const`-qualified pointer. This syntax is needed because `const int* p` produces a pointer to `const int` but not a `const` pointer to `int`. So, the `const` in `*const Var_2` serves a different role than it would in a specifier, and is grammatically allowed only because it is part of the `*const` operator. However, `const` alone is not a valid operator that can appear in a declarator, and when you put it after the comma, then it can't be a specifier anymore.

Comment: so in other words no other specifier can modify the base type specifier, i.e. in int Var_1, const Var_1; the base type specifier int (which has been common to all the declarators) is getting modified/restricted which is grammatically incorrect whereas when a *const modifies (the pointer not the base type specifier) which is a part of declarator hence it is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail, the grammar for a declaration is a *decl-specifier-seq* followed by an *init-declarator-list* followed by a semicolon.

In your declaration, `int` is the *decl-specifier-seq*, and `Var1 = 3, *const Var_2 = 34` is the *init-declarator-list*.  The latter term means a comma-separated list of declarators that might have initializers.

The definition of *declarator* involves that it must be one of the following:

- another declarator in parentheses
- another declarator preceded by optional attributes and qualifiers, all preceded by `*`, `&`, `&&`, or `T::*`
- another declarator followed by various qualifiers/attributes/etc.
- an identifier, optionally followed by attributes.

So `Var1` is a declarator because it's an identifier.  `*const Var2` is a declarator under the second bullet point.  But `const Var2` does not match any of the above rules.

---

Why are the rules the way they are? I can't say exactly but I would assume that adding a rule that "qualifiers declarator" is also a declarator would introduce problems, such as ambiguous parsing of declarations that are currently valid.

For example `int const x, y;`.  If `const x` were a declarator, then this could be parsed in two different ways -- one of which `y` is an `int` and the other `y` a `const int`.

But in the actual rules, since `const x` is not a declarator, the only possible parse is for `int const` to be the *decl-specifier-seq*, and `x, y` to be the declarator list.